# HTML codding creating area for text

Tags: html

Image of what i plan to do:

[image: Draft]

Need help to actually add those kind of text box so i can type in it. i am currently only using field set but i have no ideal on how to give it a location. If anyone have any ideal on how to do it please do teach me..
-A beginner at codding.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Assignment 2 </title>
 <!--    -->

</head>
<body>
 <center><h1 Style=color:Lime> Movie review<h1></center>
 <img src="movie logo.jpg" width="200" height="200" border="2" alt="Logo">
 <br>
 <fieldset>
     Commedy movie
 </fieldset>
 <hr>
 <center>
 <a href="https://www.rottentomatoes.com/">For more Movies Review click here.</a>
 </center>
</body>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to learn to use some tools and there are many different way to do that. You can use [html tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) to position blocs where you want or [the framework bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp) or [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

For basic stuff I think flex box should be faster for you: an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

  <head>
   <title>Assignment 2 </title>
  </head>

  <body>

     <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center">   

       <div style="height: 100px;width: 100px; background-color: aqua; margin: 15px;">Bloc 1</div>
       <div style="height: 100px;width: 100px; background-color:coral; margin: 15px;">Bloc 2</div>

     </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Using that method isit possible for me to add in hyperlink in the text so i can link it to another webpage? Also how can i find the coords when i want to set the text boxes and position my images?